# Bug? A closed-as-dupe question does not have a link to the dupe

Tags: bug, status-completed

Here's what I see when I open [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/264015/load-sql-dump-into-schema)

[image]

Notice there's no link to the dupe after "This question already exists". The comment with the link is also gone. This looks like a bug, as the question as it is now is entirely useless.

Comment: Well the issue has not been replicated on meta (I accepted your question as the duplicate target of mine and the link works).

Comment: The automatic duplicate link was also removed from my meta post.

Comment: Closing your meta question was meant as a meta joke, btw.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345289/closed-as-a-duplicate-but-the-duplicate-list-is-empty

Comment: This is now resolved. See the meta.SE link.